# stuck on purple screen when installing 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I've tried to install ubuntu for the last two days, but every time i got stuck on the purple screen with ubuntu logo and 5 dots.

When installation freezes I get this error:
amd-vi event logged [iotlb_inv_timeout]
and something like SQUASHFS error: unable to read frag (i can't read, scrolling too fast)

My computer:
HP 15-ba054nl (AMD Quad-Core A10-9600P, Radeon R7 M440 2GB, ram 16GB)
Windows 10 installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)